# UIInterfaceOrientation not responding to code

Tags: xcode, ios9, uiinterfaceorientation, landscape-portrait

I have an App that requires two Orientations Portrait and LandScape. I have followed the documentation link at bottom.  But my ViewControllers that need to be in Portrait still rotate to landscape. I am trying to update an old app that worked fine before iOS 9 and Xcode 7.0 updates, the other thing is that I started a new project and the below code responds to the proper Orientation.

Any help is much appreciated.

Configuring the View Rotation Settings

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation      {

return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}
```

Per the documentation ShouldAutorotate , supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation will present your View according

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotate

Comment: How does your app get from one view controller to another?

Comment: The transition is modal no push, as far as i know when push is used the view controller takes the orientation from the parent view controller. So using modal should work. IS that correct ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? You are not really providing any information about what you're doing.

Comment: Hello Matt, thanks again for the follow-up. In my application , i have the need for a portrait and landscape views. There is only one view that requires landscape all others are portrait. When the app launches the only orientation should be portrait, since updating to iOS 9 my code that dictates the orientation is not responding and all views now will rotate when they did not before the update. Not sure if i can be any clearer. Thanks again for your time and help. JZ